# PHP & MYSQL: Select from where id=$id

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

So I'm making a usergroup function that allows me to block off pages to lower user levels. This is my function for grabbing info:

```
function grab_info($id, $requested_info){
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $requested_info = $requested_info;
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'login');
    if ($con->connect_errno >0){
        die("Handle your connection error here");
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $id";
    if (!$result = $con->query($sql)) {
        die("There as a query error for some reason handle your query error");
    }
    while($row = $result-fetch_assoc()){
        $info = $row[$requested_info];
        return $info;
    }
}
```

Right here:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $id";
if (!$result = $con->query($sql)) {
    die("There as a query error for some reason handle your query error");
}
```

is where something is going wrong. This is my method for grabbing the info:

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$rank = grab_info($id, 'rank');//Gets rank from our id
$meets = can_access($rank, 4, true);//We're saying our user has a rank of 1 to access this page you need a rank of 3 and only 3 hence strict
if ($meets == false){//user cant access page
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}
```

Basically, it just keeps giving me the "There as a query error for some reason handle your query error" and I'm stuck. New to php so sorry if it's messy.

Comment: Check if `$id` is not null and something ! You're putting a raw variable into a query without filtering it and that means SQL INJECTION ! In your example because the entry comes from the session it's Ok but still think about INJECTION

Comment: Can you var_dump the session? And show results

Answer (score 3):

Using prepared statements and cast the variable as an integer.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
$id = (int) $_SESSION['user_id'];
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: Also, point to note: never select *. Only select what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that $id is actually set. If it's null that will cause your query to explode.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='{$id}'";
```

Try this :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email='$user_email');
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -1):

```
Please try this: 



function grab_info($id, $requested_info){
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $requested_info = $requested_info;
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'login');
    if ($con->connect_errno >0){
        die("Handle your connection error here");
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =". $id;
    if (!$result = $con->query($sql)) {
        die("There as a query error for some reason handle your query error");
    }
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $info = $row;
        return $info;
    }
}
```

Comment: $requested_info = $requested_info ?? Why is that needed?

Comment: Well for one, id and requested info are being overwritten inside the function so why are things being passed in? For two, return info inside a while loop of a function will return only the first row. This isn’t even proper PHP syntax.

Comment: Yes I know its overwrite the value as i don't take array there but as per question i just only give the answer for query line. another thing i also don't know that how many value are there db and how many value user want and many thing but i only give answer for that single line of query. other all code i copied from question as well.